# sequential queries in MongoDB queries not working properly sometimes

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am executing 2 update queries in sequential manner. I am using **generator function** & **yield** to handle asynchronous behaviour of javascript.

```
var result = yield db.tasks.update({
                    "_id": task._id,
                    "taskLog":{$elemMatch:{"currentApproverRole": vcurrentApproverRole,
                    "currentApprover": new RegExp(employeeCode, 'i')}}
                }, {
                    $set: {
                        "taskPendingAt": vnextApproverEmpCode,
                        "status": vactionTaken,
                        "lastUpdated": vactionTakenTime,
                        "lastUpdatedBy": employeeCode,
                        "shortPin":shortPin,
                        "workFlowDetails":task.workFlowDetails,
                        "taskLog.$.reason": reason,
                        "taskLog.$.actionTakenBy": employeeCode,
                        "taskLog.$.actionTakenByName": loggedInUser.firstName+" "+loggedInUser.lastName,
                        "taskLog.$.actionTaken": vactionTaken,
                        "taskLog.$.actionTakenTime": vactionTakenTime
                    }
                });
                var vstatus = vactionTaken;

       // Below is the query that is not working properly sometimes

                yield db.groupPicnic.update({"gppTaskId": task.workFlowDetails.gppTaskId, "probableParticipantList.employeeCode": task.createdBy}, 
                    {
                        $set: {
                            'probableParticipantList.$.applicationStatus': vactionTaken
                        }
                    })
```

Second update operation does not execute sometimes (Works 9 out of 10 times). I don't seem to figure out how to handle this issue?

Comment: You're yielding a promise, are you waiting for it to resolve? can you post the generator call?

Comment: I think **yield** itself is supposed to hold the execution until query execution is complete & returns promise. Anyways, I am using it like                                        `co(function * () {    queries....   })`

Answer (score 0):

ES6 generators are supposed to provide a simple way for writing iterators.

An iterator is just a sequence of values - like an array, but consumed dynamically and produced lazily.

Currently your code does this:

```
let imAnUnresolvedPromise = co().next();
 // exiting app, promise might not resolve in time
```

By moving forward and -not- waiting on the promise (assuming your app closes) you can't guarantee that it will execute in time, hence why the unstable behaviour your experiencing.

All you have to change is to wait on the promise to resolve.

```
let resolveThis = await co().next();
```

EDIT:

Without `async`/`await` syntax you'll have to use nested callbacks to guarantee the correct order, like so:

```
co().next().then((promiseResolved) => {
     co().next().then((promiseTwoResolved) => {
         console.log("I'm done")
     })
});
```

Comment: Not sure how I can use await inside generator function

Comment: the `await` is not in the generator but on the promise it yields. you can `await` inside the generator as well but that will not give you the behaviour you want.

Comment: I tried using callback on update query but that didn't even perform update operation

Comment: my environmental dependencies are such that I can't use all ES6 features like async  & await. Is there a way I can do this by using yield only

Comment: i added callback syntax to my post.